# Fetch a parent by a child in Many-to-Many unidirectional relationship JPA

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I have two entities Estate and PropertyTags in a Spring Boot application. The Estate entity has a many-to-many relationship with the PropertyTag (PropertyTag is also used by other entities)

This is the Estate entity:

```
@Entity
public class Estate{
@Id
private Long id;
.
.

@ManyToMany
private Set<PropertyTag> propertyTags;
.
.
// other properties
}
```

And the PropertyTag class:

```
@Entity
public class PropertyTag{
@Id
private Long id;
private String tagName;

// getters and setters

}
```

The above relationship created 3 database tables with one table for foreign keys of the relationship.

I need a repository method (or query) that will retrieve an Estate that will take and argument of an estate Id and property tag object.

I tried using the hibernate keywords as below:

```
public interface EstateRepository extends JpaRepository<Estate, Long> {

    Optional<Estate> findByIdAndPropertyTagsContaining(Long estateId, PropertyTag childTag);
   
}
```

But that did not work.

I do not want to retrieve an estate via its ID and manually loop through its property tags to check if a tag exists in its collection. I feel this can be done with a query of the database

I am not so good at writing custom queries. I need help with the query to do that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an `Estate` entity by the `PropertyTag` entity you can also just use the id of the `PropertyTag` and try

```
Optional<Estate> findByIdAndPropertyTags_Id(Long estateId, Long propertyTagId);
```

Which should return the Estate containing a tag with the given ID.
`Containing` is used for String searching